# TUI image editor get the element from div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

What i am trying to do is I am taking the upload image preview and passing that image to the TUI image editor for that, I am trying something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {



    // GET THE IMAGE.
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = $("#image_upload_preview_profile").attr("src");

    // WAIT TILL IMAGE IS LOADED.
    img.onload = function() {
        create_canvas(img);       // FILL THE CANVAS WITH THE IMAGE.
    }

    function create_canvas(img) {
        //Create canvas
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.id = "CursorLayer";
        canvas.width = 1224;
        canvas.height = 768;
        canvas.style.zIndex = 8;
        canvas.style.position = "absolute";
        canvas.style.border = "1px solid";
        document.getElementById('#tui-image-editor').appendChild('canvas');
    }
});
```

By creating canvas and passing that image by taking it's src in the #tui-image-editor . But in that line I ma getting something like this append child cannot be null.
The error is in #tui-image-editor.
As we are using library for this so what is happen i am not creating any div through HTML there is only one div :

I browse this through everywhere can you suggest me this what is the proper solution for this. As i tried creating a div but that breaks the entire library.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message you get is :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

and that's because of this :

> document.getElementById('#tui-image-editor')

it should be like this (remove the #) :

> document.getElementById('tui-image-editor')

getElementById accepts the ID of the element not a selector

then your code has another issue, you're passing a string to appendChild instead of the canvas element.

the correct code would be something like this :

```
function create_canvas(img) {
    //Create canvas
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.id = "CursorLayer";
    canvas.width = 1224;
    canvas.height = 768;
    canvas.style.zIndex = 8;
    canvas.style.position = "absolute";
    canvas.style.border = "1px solid";
    document.getElementById('tui-image-editor').appendChild(canvas);
}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
    at create_canvas (image-editor.js:46)
    at Image.img.onload (image-editor.js:33)

Comment: Are you sure you have a div with the id 'tui-image-editor' in your html ?

Comment: No I don't have what i am trying to do is I am implementing TUI Image Editor. THis is my updated code 
  document.getElementById('tui-image-editor-container').appendChild(canvas);

So what will happen when clicking this the #image_upload_preview_profile will load and i can do edit in this image

Comment: Then create a div with the id "tui-image-editor" then this should work